# Best practice for will-move-from parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

According to the core guidelines:

> F.18: For “will-move-from” parameters, pass by X&& and std::move the parameter

The example is:

```
void sink(vector<int>&& v) {   // sink takes ownership of whatever the argument owned
    // usually there might be const accesses of v here
    store_somewhere(std::move(v));
    // usually no more use of v here; it is moved-from
}
```

I noticed that I tend to use smart pointers for all objects except cheaply-copied (which I almost always consider only primitives). So I almost always use the following guidelines:

```
void sink(std::unique_ptr<OtherThanPrimitive> p) {
    // use p ... possibly std::move(p) onward somewhere else
}   // p gets destroyed
```

I started to consider if I use best practice. What I can think of as advantage of the first approach is forcing caller of a function to explicitly std::move and it makes code cleaner. In the second approach move constructor will be called two times, but for smart pointer it's not a big cost. Considering above I started to think about changing my habit to use the first approach always for collections that I am sure that support moving (so most of STL collections). Second approach for custom objects (I assume that cost of considering writing custom move constructor for a class outstrips the profit of readability). Is there any best practice that covers that? What approach do you usually apply? Am I missing something in my justification?

Comment: It's assumed that if you take a movable type by value that it'll be moved from, because the function itself owns it and can do whatever it wants with it. Also you shouldn't just pass everything as dynamic resources like you do with `unique_ptr`... that's the whole point of having move semantics. And not writing a move constructor in the name of readability is frankly silly and inefficient

Comment: Unrelated: I may be misinterpreting your writing, but if not you may want to rethink why you use the smart pointers. Cheap copying is not what they are for.  Use smart pointers to automatically manage the lifetime of an object that would otherwise be manually managed. Use references for cheap copying.

Comment: So you use `sink` like `sink(std::make_unique<OtherThanPrimitive>(std::move(my_obj)))`? I'm not one to focus on saving on key strokes but this doesn't seem practical (setting aside other considerations). Or do you *only* use `sink` with `unique_ptr` owned objects?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but move semantic does not make any sense without dynamically allocated objects (either by smart pointers or raw). Imagine huge object constructed from a class with statically allocated members only. The member types have also statically allocated members. When you go further you have primitives that are not movable. So in that situation there is no point, I believe to write move constructor. If you move it will be copied anyway. 
To not copy all the time the object is passed around it's dynamically allocated and pointers are passed around.

Answer (score 0):

> What I can think of as advantage of the first approach is forcing caller of a function to explicitly std::move and it makes code cleaner. In the second approach move constructor will be called two times, but for smart pointer it's not a big cost.

Between `void sink(T&&)` and `void sink(T)`: both require `std::move` for move-only types or to invoke the move constructor. The second form can also copy, given a copyable lvalue argument. If `T` is not cheap to copy, silently getting a copy can be a disadvantage. The second form, even when used with a move-only type, will have an extra move, into the function parameter, compared to the first approach. If `T` is not cheap to move, that can be a disadvantage. When moving into a data member, or otherwise logically making a copy of the argument, the second form allows one overload accepting both T&& and const T& arguments, instead of having one overload for each, and then 2^N overloads for N arguments.

However, the second form unconditionally moves from the argument. The first may conditionally move from the argument or not move from the argument at all. The caller cannot tell (bad!).  The second form provides a clearer expression of intent.

Note that issue [526](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/526) has a nice little helper function `copy` which you could use with the first form for not so cheaply copyable types, to make a copy explicit. With that helper, you can move by default, with the minimum number of moves, and opt in to an explicit copy. The signature still provides less clarity of intent than the second form.

> Considering above I started to think about changing my habit to use the first approach always for collections that I am sure that support moving (so most of STL collections). Second approach for custom objects

I don't think custom objects versus move-supporting collections is the right distinction. If `T` is not movable, the parameter should be `const T&` or `T` (if you want a copy). Using the first form in that case does not make sense.

If `T` is movable, as a rule of thumb, use the core guidelines. Use the first form. If `T` is cheaply movable, use the second form.

> I assume that cost of considering writing custom move constructor for a class outstrips the profit of readability

One shouldn't need to write custom move constructors for most classes. Something owns the storage. That needs a custom move constructor. Internal bookkeeping that point into the storage generate the need for a custom move constructor. So, containers. And if you're writing a container for general use with supplied types, one should probably write a move constructor if it could be more efficient. Doing otherwise might be more surprising.